# How do I replace the "From" address from my mailings?

Tags: civimail

I setup a default adress in **CiviMail -> From Email Adresses** , like this :

`"Example" <example@example.org>`

but the problem is that when I send mails, the "From adress" change and become :

`"Example" <xxxx@gmail.com>`

(I specify that I use a gmail account in the SMTP sending settings)

Is it possible to force that mailing adress so it become "example@example.org" ?

At the begining, I was using a private adress (in my own domain) for civiCRM SMTP's settings (and it worked fine), but lately we need to migrate these mails to Office365 / Exchange mails and I have never been able to get CiviCRM mailings to work with the new Office365/Outlook/Exchange settings, that's why I opted for an SMTP account that uses gmail.

Comment: have you checked both /civicrm/admin/domain?action=update&reset=1 and /civicrm/admin/options/from_email_address?reset=1

Comment: I try the first link ( `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fdomain%3Faction%3Dupdate&reset=1` in my wordpress )  and I land on the admin page with no particular message.
I try the second with `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/options/from_email_address?reset=1` but I got an error

and it seems like I got the same problem with the "from" email changing.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion The error in log file : https://pastebin.com/raw/b4SyVE1u

Comment: also, I replaced the "?" with a "&" in the second link and it seems to works, I land on the "From Email Adresses" page , but the xxx@gmail.com email continues to appear in the From field of my mailings.

Comment: What version of Civi are you running? Just a note that in 4.7.30 they removed the duplicate 'From email address' setting in the organizational contact that petednz is referring to in the first link.

Comment: @RayWright I use version 5.5.1

Comment: Pretty sure that's an effect of sending via Gmail - it's an anti-spoofing thing if you try to send with a non-gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

So I am assuming that the only thing that changed between "it worked" and "it doesn't" is to switch from your own smtp to your gmail one.

Beside the problem you mention, using smtp from gmail will not work to send mass emails, they have a lot of limits and as soon as your list has more than a handful of emails, you will have problems.

There as several providers (sendgrid, mailjet...) that are integrated with civi, and I'd recommend you switching to one of them

And it should solve out your gmail.com problem too